# ERROR PIP installing beeswithmachineguns on OSX

Tags: load-testing

I kept getting an error when trying to run

```
sudo pip install beeswithmachineguns on my macbook
```

Error log looked like this:

> warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building
>   Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
>
> building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
>
> clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
>
> clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a
>   warning) in the future
>
> error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

I figured out what was causing this see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this straight away as a reference for anyone else with this problem.

The issue was that the latest (5.1) version of Xcode ships with a compiler that treats unknown passed parameters as errors, there is a post here which gives you a command to bypass the "error"

http://bruteforce.gr/bypassing-clang-error-unknown-argument.html

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install beeswithmachineguns
```